# Detect if website installed/opened as app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Edge/Chrome allows "install website as an app", which allow launch website in separate window as standalone application, with its own icon, be able to pin to taskbar/start menu, basically creating a web app.

Is there a way detect when website is viewed in such "app"?

Why I need this, is because these windows display both title you gave when created the app (which by default is the website's title) and title of the website, more ofthen than not, it will show double title. So, I'd like automatically change title on website when it's viewed in the app.

I've tried research and people suggested use `navigator.standalone` or `matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches` but I think it's for websites opened in a `webView` of nodejs or such (?), both method return `false`

Comment: When chrome gives you a prompt to install, that is because that site was made as a Progressive Web App. More info here: https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/

Comment: There is a section on detection if the PWA is installed here : https://web.dev/learn/pwa/detection/

Comment: @Steve oh, so that's where `navigator.standalone` come into play? That's different from "install website as an app" that Edge offers though. PWA requires website to suport that, "install website as an app" - can be used on any website.

Comment: Interesting. I see what you are talking about. I'm not sure. If I find anything I'll update.